# Finding the difference between 2 times stored as strings in Swift 4

Tags: swift, date, time, swift4, intervals

I have 2 times stored as strings and I am trying to find the difference between them in hours and minutes and display it in a label, I am pretty sure I have to use `DateFormatter` to get a date from string but from that point I am lost as to the best way to get the difference, some stuff I have read says to use interval, other says use calendar. I can't seem to come up with anything that is clear to me.

```
var dailyTimeOut: NSDate {
    get{
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .medium
        return formatter.date(from: finishTimeLabel.text!)! as NSDate
    }
}

func calculateHours() {

    let interval = dailyTimeOut.timeIntervalSince(dailyTimeIn as Date)
    // print("\(stringFromTimeInterval(interval: interval))")

    let totalTime = stringFromTimeInterval(interval: interval)

    totalTimeLabel.text = totalTime
}

func stringFromTimeInterval(interval: TimeInterval) -> String {
    let interval = Int(interval)
    let minutes = (interval / 60) % 60
    let hours = (interval / 3600)
    return String(format: "%02d:%02d", hours, minutes)
}
```

Comment: FWIW, I'd suggest excising `NSDate` from your Swift code. Use `Date` and only bridge to `NSDate` where needed.

Comment: As an aside, I’m not crazy about having computed property extracting value from a label, either. This seems to conflate the model and the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you want `Date` objects for your two strings:

```
let string1 = "13:00"
let string2 = "15:30"

guard let time1 = time(from: string1), let time2 = time(from: string2) else {
    print("not valid time strings")
    return
}
```

Where

```
private let timeFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    return formatter
}()

private func time(from timeString: String) -> Date? {
    return timeFormatter.date(from: timeString)
}
```

Then, if you want it as a nicely formatted string, you can use [`DateComponentsFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/datecomponentsformatter):

```
let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute]
let string = formatter.string(from: time1, to: time2)!
```

Yielding:

> 2:30

Or, if you want the hour and minute as numerical values, you can use [`Calendar`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar) method [`dateComponents(_:from:to:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2292887-datecomponents):

```
let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: time1, to: time2)
let hour = components.hour!
let minutes = components.minute!
```

Comment: I imagine this code will work in virtually all situations but I can envision some weird edge case where you end up with two dates where there is some leap second or time change or something that ends up giving the wrong result. Since the strings are just times and are not associated with dates, it might be better to parse the strings without a `DateFormatter`. Or actually the `DateFormatter` is fine, it's `DateComponentsFormatter` that could, in theory, give the wrong result. Not sure it's worth the effort though.

Comment: I agree. The concept of interpreting times in the absence of dates is dangerous. E.g., if you're working at NORAD and what to know how long your shift was from 1:00am to 9:00am, the answer will be different on March 11th than it would be on March 12th. But he used date formatter, so I didn't want to open that can of worms (other than replace `NSDate` with `Date` and encourage him not to instantiate formatters repeatedly). My key goal was to show him how to get elapsed hours and minutes from two `Date` objects, either as string or as numerical values.

Comment: Great, that helps a lot I am getting an error printed to the console the "Not valid time string" could that be because my string includes the date and time I am using date format medium and time format short to create the string in the first place from a UI pickerView?

Comment: @rayray - If you have a picker view, you should grab the `Date` from that and completely bypass converting it to a string and then back to a `Date`.

Comment: The problem i saw with using the picker view directly is that this is for a time sheet app so a person logs in using one button at the beginning and that date and time is stored in a realm then at the end they use another button to log out and that is stored in realm as well. I am trying to have the total time calculated right after they use the button to log out, as the popup with the date picker exits the view and populates the current view with the time out but before it is all reserved to realm. I hope that I am making sense with this I am very new to coding.

Comment: When dates are saved in Realm, they should be saved as native `Date` objects, if Realm supports that. Or if you have to save it as a string, then store it in ISO 8601/RFC 3339 format and convert that back to a `Date` object. But you never want to save date strings in a localized format (e.g. the medium format) because what if the user changes their locale? ISO 8601 is an unambiguous format.

Comment: And I thought I had it, I have it displaying the total time now. But reading your comment above I think I am going to have to go back to the drawing board and change how I am saving to Realm, Thank you for the great advice.